# Draw ArcTo on canvas

Tags: javafx

I have a `List<PathElement>` that I would like to be able to either add to the scenegraph, or draw to canvas. The first is easy, as I can just create a Path node and add it to the scene. The second requires mapping from `PathElement`'s to calls on `GraphicsContext`. For most things this is pretty straightforward except for `ArcTo` and `GraphicsContext.arcTo` which are parameterized differently.

ArcTo accepts the following `ArcTo(double radiusX, double radiusY, double xAxisRotation, double x, double y, boolean largeArcFlag, boolean sweepFlag)`

Whereas `GraphicsContext.arcTo` accepts `arcTo(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2, double radius)`. Additionally, `GraphicsContext` has `arc` which accepts `arc(double centerX, double centerY, double radiusX, double radiusY, double startAngle, double length)`.

How can an `ArcTo`be drawn on a canvas using the methods available in `GraphicsContext`?

Comment: The guy wrote a translator. I don't know if it works https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28043935/javafx-how-can-a-path-be-painted-on-a-graphicscontext. Look at the comments of Jewelsea's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this link of example will help you out.

[Working with Canvas | JavaFx 2](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/canvas/jfxpub-canvas.htm)