# How do i color my path and background in this javafx program

Tags: javafx

I am drawing this object in JavaFx. I have filled my scene with Red,  I want to set a fill to my object with a color, lets say white and a stroke similar to the background red. Help me out if you will.
The program looks like this

[image]

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.scene.shape.ArcType;
import javafx.scene.paint.*;

public class Person extends Application
{
public static void main (String[] args)
 {
 launch(args);
 }  

public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception
{
    Group root =new Group();
    Scene scene=new Scene(root,Color.RED);
    Canvas canvas=new Canvas(400,600);//l,w
    GraphicsContext Gc=canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();

    Gc.beginPath();
    Gc.moveTo(253,301);
    Gc.bezierCurveTo(249,280,244,267,239,249);
    Gc.bezierCurveTo(240,242,240,235,241,225);
    Gc.lineTo(249,241);
    Gc.bezierCurveTo(250,253,252,274,253,301);
    Gc.lineTo(245,319);
    Gc.lineTo(245,338);
    Gc.lineTo(248,330);
    Gc.lineTo(253,320);
    Gc.lineTo(253,338);
    Gc.lineTo(242,352);
    Gc.lineTo(245,352);
    Gc.lineTo(261,335);

    //Gc.moveTo(261,335);
    Gc.bezierCurveTo(265,315,268,283,271,260);
    Gc.lineTo(270,225);
    Gc.bezierCurveTo(267,213,264,187,261,169);
    Gc.arcTo(259,162,257,158,10);

    //Gc.moveTo(257,158);
    Gc.bezierCurveTo(245,150,231,142,215,130);

    //Gc.moveTo(215,130);
    Gc.lineTo(211,118);
    Gc.lineTo(218,111);

    Gc.bezierCurveTo(219,104,220,95,220,80);
    Gc.arc(198.5,80,21.5,21.5,0,180);
    Gc.bezierCurveTo(177,95,178,104,179,111);

    Gc.lineTo(186,118);
    Gc.lineTo(182,130);
    Gc.bezierCurveTo(164,142,153,150,140,158);
    ///Gc.bezierCurveTo()
    Gc.arcTo(137,162,135,169,10);
    Gc.bezierCurveTo(132,187,129,213,126,225);
    Gc.lineTo(125,260);
    Gc.bezierCurveTo(130,283,134,315,135,335);
    Gc.lineTo(153,352);
    Gc.lineTo(156,352);
    Gc.lineTo(145,338);
    Gc.lineTo(145,320);
    Gc.lineTo(150,330);
    Gc.lineTo(153,338);
    Gc.lineTo(153,319);
    Gc.lineTo(145,301);
    Gc.bezierCurveTo(146,274,148,253,149,241);
    Gc.lineTo(157,225);
    Gc.bezierCurveTo(158,235,158,242,159,249);
    Gc.bezierCurveTo(155,267,150,280,145,301);
    //left leg
    Gc.moveTo(153,352);
    //Gc.lineTo(153,360);
    Gc.bezierCurveTo(154,337,157,398,158,440);
    Gc.bezierCurveTo(159,465,160,483,164,498);
    Gc.lineTo(163,512);
    Gc.lineTo(164,520);//arc
    Gc.bezierCurveTo(162,523,159,534,155,540);
    Gc.lineTo(184,540);//Bottomline
    Gc.bezierCurveTo(180,534,179,527,178,517);
    Gc.lineTo(178,506);//arc
    Gc.lineTo(178,488);
    Gc.bezierCurveTo(180,465,182,447,185,416);
    Gc.bezierCurveTo(187,396,192,363,198,330);
    //next leg

    Gc.bezierCurveTo(204,365,209,396,211,416);
    Gc.bezierCurveTo(214,447,216,465,218,488);
    Gc.lineTo(218,506);
    Gc.lineTo(218,527);//arc
    Gc.bezierCurveTo(217,527,216,534,212,540);
    Gc.lineTo(249,540);

    Gc.bezierCurveTo(249,534,241,523,239,520);
    Gc.lineTo(240,512);//arc
    Gc.lineTo(241,498);
    Gc.bezierCurveTo(241,483,242,465,243,440);
    Gc.bezierCurveTo(243,398,244,377,246,352);


    Gc.stroke();

    root.getChildren().add(canvas);
    primaryStage.setTitle("Person JavafX");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();

    }
}
```

Any suggestions or modifications will be appreciated

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are trying to achieve. "fill to my object with a color, lets say white and a stroke similar to the background red"  what object do you want to fill with white ?

Comment: i want my person to be filled with white, i want the background(Anything outside the outline) to remain red. The person outline drawn in black, i want it in white/red.,, i only want white and red in my scene, thats it

Comment: `Gc.setFill(Color.WHITE);
    Gc.fill();`  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28053209/3992939) answer might be helpful.